# Get only table data and not all table data with a class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying scrape a website, loop through to get only the state names and not all the classes in the table data. But when I loop through it gives all table data is there a way to exclude the td class?

```
page = requests.get("https://www.theguardian.com/world/ng-interactive/2020/apr/13/coronavirus-map-us-latest-covid-19-cases-state-by-state")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
state_table = soup.find(id='co-table-container')
item_cases = state_table.find(class_='co-table')
states = [s.get_text() for s in item_cases.find_all('td')]
print(states)
```

Comment: Can you show the current and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.theguardian.com/world/ng-interactive/2020/apr/13/coronavirus-map-us-latest-covid-19-cases-state-by-state')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# get all rows from the table with class: co-table
rows = soup.find('table', {'class':'co-table'}).findAll('tr')

# loop through each row to get the state name
# note that we skip first row; we don't want the heading
for i in range(1, len(rows)):
    print(rows[i].td.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `strip()` function. something like following

```
 page = requests.get("https://www.theguardian.com/world/ng- 
 interactive/2020/apr/13/coronavirus-map-us-latest-covid-19-cases-state-by-state")
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
 state_table = soup.find(id='co-table-container')
 item_cases = state_table.find(class_='co-table')
 data = []

 for tr in item_cases.find_all("tr"):
    _class = tr.get("class")
    myData = {}

    #skip table body header
    if _class is not None and "thead" == _class[0]:
        continue

    #scrape details
    for td in tr.find_all("td"):
        myData[td['data-stat']] = td.text.strip()

        """ add if condition like if you want to exclude any specific 

            # find about td['data-stat'] when you inspect in table row columns
            if td['data-stat'] == "name":
                myData['name'] = td.text.strip()

        """

    data.append(myData)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `pandas` function `read_html()`. It uses beautifulsoup under the hood to parse `<table>` tags in html.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.theguardian.com/world/ng-interactive/2020/apr/13/coronavirus-map-us-latest-covid-19-cases-state-by-state'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0].dropna(axis=1)

print (list(df['State/territory']))
```

**Output:**

```
['New York', 'New Jersey', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'California', 'Pennsylvania', 'Illinois', 'Florida', 'Louisiana', 'Texas', 'Georgia', 'Connecticut', 'Washington', 'Maryland', 'Indiana', 'Colorado', 'Ohio', 'Virginia', 'Tennessee', 'North Carolina', 'Missouri', 'Alabama', 'Arizona', 'Wisconsin', 'South Carolina', 'Rhode Island', 'Mississippi', 'Nevada', 'Utah', 'Kentucky', 'Oklahoma', 'District of Columbia', 'Delaware', 'Iowa', 'Minnesota', 'Oregon', 'Arkansas', 'Kansas', 'Idaho', 'New Mexico', 'South Dakota', 'New Hampshire', 'Puerto Rico', 'Nebraska', 'Maine', 'Vermont', 'West Virginia', 'Hawaii', 'Montana', 'North Dakota', 'Alaska', 'Wyoming', 'Guam', 'Virgin Islands']
```